# how to add daily events via command-line?

Tags: command-line, calendar, events

Is there any way to add the our events from he terminal ? I know the GUI way but I want to do it from the terminal .

Comment: Can you clarify? What are "our events"? About which calendar are you talking?

Comment: I am talking about the calender which comes with cal command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a CLI tool named as pal.
we can install it by using `sudo apt-get install pal` in the terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

[image]
for more information : [pal man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/pal.1.html)